# Right justify columns in border matrix

Tags: bordermatrix

I would like to right justify the columns in a border matrix. Is this possible? Default seems to be centre

```
 \documentclass{article} 
 \begin{document}

    $
     \bordermatrix{~ & 5 & 6\cr
                  5 & 1 & 0 \cr
                  6 & 0 & -1 \cr}
    $
 \end{document}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't know if it is possible with `bordermatrix`, but it is with `kbordermatrix` by issuing

```
\kbalignrighttrue
```

The following lines are to simulate the behavior of `bordermatrix`

```
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
\renewcommand{\kbrowstyle}{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\kbcolstyle}{\displaystyle}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{kbordermatrix}
\kbalignrighttrue
\renewcommand{\kbldelim}{(}
\renewcommand{\kbrdelim}{)}
\renewcommand{\kbrowstyle}{\displaystyle}
\renewcommand{\kbcolstyle}{\displaystyle}

\begin{document}

    $
     \kbordermatrix{~ & 5 & 6\cr
                  5 & 1 & 0 \cr
                  6 & 0 & -1 \cr}
    $

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Answer (score 0):

A solution with `{pNiceMatrix}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

% the key 'r' requires a right-justification 
$\begin{pNiceMatrix}[first-col,first-row,r]
  & 5 & 6 \\
5 & 1 & 0 \\
6 & 0 & -1 \\
\end{pNiceMatrix}$

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]